# Random Undefined method to_sym for array error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving strange random undefined method error (the one on the title). I'm using rubymine IDE and when I receive this error I have to close it and restart the thin server. It has no pattern, suddenly it just throws this error/

The error is:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for Array
```

It happens on sections on the code where i access the children of a certain model. Lets say the parent model is Account, Account has_many Items. When the error is thrown, each section of the rails app where i try to access the items of the account (@account.items), it returns that error. What can be the causes? Im attaching the stack trace and the model architecture summarized:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    has_many :orders, :through => :items
end
```

Database for development is MySql.

**UPDATE:**

Stacktrace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `to_sym' for #<Array:0x00000006a6daa0>:
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:60:in      `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:24:in `attribute_cast_code'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:80:in `attribute_cast_code'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in    `define_external_attribute_method'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define_attribute_methods'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:67:in `block in  define_attribute_methods'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:63:in  `define_attribute_methods'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `respond_to?'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:398:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_find_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/base.rb:523:in `init_with'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:68:in `instantiate'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:8:in `rescue in each'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
app/views/management_objectives/_items.html.erb:30:in   `_app_views_management_objectives__items_html_erb__2456651386413182339_56758500'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:15:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
app/views/management_objectives/index.html.erb:64:in `_app_views_management_objectives_index_html_erb__4056717196502282234_46342800'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/tommy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
wicked_pdf (0.9.6) lib/pdf_helper.rb:23:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__565611819153590293__process_action__1000043893493154013__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4036826611890793859__call__3734749657817228653__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14) lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:127:in `debug_program'
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14) bin/rdebug-ide:118:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `<main>'
script/rails:0:in `<main>'
```

**Update 2**

Related Views. *Notice:*, the error is not specific view related, it happens in all views where access to the collection of items of an account occurs

manage_objectices/_items.html.erb:

```
<table class="products-table">
<% if items.count > 0 %>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable_objectives "title", t(:'activerecord.attributes.item.title'),
                     sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%= sortable_objectives "visits", t(:'activerecord.attributes.item.visits'),
                     sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%= sortable_objectives "sales", t(:'activerecord.attributes.item.sold_quantity'),
                     sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>
    <th><%=sortable_objectives "questions", t(:'activerecord.models.question.other'),
                    sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%=sortable_objectives "conversions", t(:'private.orders.statistics.management_objectives.conversions'),
                    sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%=sortable_objectives "question_rates", t(:'private.orders.statistics.management_objectives.question_rate'),
                    sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%=sortable_objectives "objectives", t(:'private.orders.statistics.management_objectives.objectives'),
                    sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>

    <th><%=sortable_objectives "successful_rates", t(:'private.orders.statistics.management_objectives.successful_rates'),
                    sort_param_name, direction_param_name %></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <% items.each do |item| %>
          <%= render :partial => "single_item", :locals => {:item => item} %>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
<% else %>
<%= t(:'private.items.no_items')%>
<% end %>
</table>
<%= paginate items, :theme => "mercadopro", :param_name => page_param_name, :params =>    {:tab => page_param_name} %>
```

management_objectives/_items.html.erb:

```
<tr>
  <td class="info">
    <h3><span class="fade"></span><%= link_to item.title,  mercadopro_account_account_item_path(current_mercadopro_account,current_account,item.id) %>        </h3>
    <p>#<%= item.ml_id %>  |  <%= item_listing_type(item) %>  |  <%= item_ends_in(item) %>      </p>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= item.visits %>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= item.sold_quantity %>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= item.questions.count%>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= number_to_percentage(item.conversions_percentage)%>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= number_to_percentage(item.question_rate)%>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
    <%= item.available_quantity%>
  </td>
  <td class="number">
     <%= number_to_percentage(item.objective_accomplished_percentage)%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: post the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: Oops, stacktrace added

Comment: Post `app/views/management_objectives/_items.html.erb` content.